# Zeppelin notebooks on Windows 7

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have failed to install Apache Zeppelin (v. 0.7.1) on my Windows 7 desktop. 
I would like to proceed without having to install Docker, however.
I tried reinstalling the Java runtime etc. but Zeppelin does not start.
Any suggestions?

(I am aware of version 0.7.3 but don't feel like wasting even more time trying it on Windows 7).

Comment: The installation is quite simple (at least for Linux but for Windows it seems to be the same). So you have followed https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/install/install.html (0.7.3. vs 0.7.1 does not matter) and at which step do you have which problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the errors your are getting. Confirm you have made all the settings (environmental or otherwise) as required.

Comment: Hello, I tried Zeppelin 0.7.3 and now it runs with only minor warnings on Win 7 with jre 1.8.0. Thanks.